Is $X = \max \left\{X_1, X_2\right\}$ exponential variable given $X_1$ and $X_2$ are?
I know that if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent exponential variables with parameters $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ then $X = \min \{X_1, X_2\}$ is exponential, and with $\lambda = \lambda_1+\lambda_2$.
I wonder if $X = \max \{X_1, X_2 \}$ is also an exponential variable. I attempted to approach this by considering $\min \{X_1, X_2\}+ \max \{X_1, X_2\}=X_1+X_2$, but without success.

HINT: use more general fact: $$
F_{X_{(n)}}(x) = \mathbb{P}(X_{(n)} \le x) = \mathbb{P}(X_1 \le x, \ldots, X_n \le x) = \prod_{i \le n} \mathbb{P}(X_i \le x)
$$

Thanks! That is a wonderful hint! I was stuck using $P(X_n\geq x) = P(X_1\geq x)P(X_2\geq x)$ which worked well with min, but not with max.

You have $P(X \le x) = P(X_1 \le x, X_2 \le x) = P(X_1 \le x) P(X_2 \le x)$, where the second equality holds because $X_1$ and $X_2$ are independent.
Now you can write
$$P(X_1 \le x) P(X_2 \le x)= (1 - e^{\lambda_1 x}) (1-e^{-\lambda_2 x})$$
and that's not the CDF of an exponential random variable.

I think you meant CDF

Thanks, Jose.  Changed.
